# How to build a raised paver patio against the house

Tags: patio, pavers

We recently put in a retaining wall and raised paver patio/walk around one side of the house, wrapping to the back. I'd like to have a higher level patio so that you can walk (or push a wheelchair, etc) straight out the door like you would with a deck. It would have a walk to tie into the existing paver area. There are several issues.

Directly under the sliding door is a basement window. That is probably going to have to go away. (Where the door is was originally just a bay window; it was replaced with the door because there was no door at all on the back of the house.)

There are a couple of downspouts that would be in the patio area. Put PVC pipe around them and build up to that?

What do you do about the cedar siding? I assume it has to be removed and replaced with something that won't rot? All the work on the side and the other end was at the foundation, not above it.

[image: Back of the house]

[image: raised pavers on side]

Comment: Why not just have a deck?  Then you don't have to worry about the window, walls or the pipes.

Comment: Wish I could figure out how to add a second pic. We really like the pavers and already have a large section of that. So we'd like to add this and connect.

Comment: This is very difficult to do at any point but the design phase when you can make the relevant parts of the house from masonry. Putting rot-proof siding over wood sheathing and framing just moves where the rot happens when you bury the wall.